# MySQL Query not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    p.Requestor AS Requestor,
    p.AdjAmtOrd AS Amount_Ordered,
    p.Vendor_Name AS Vendor,
    p.Item_Description AS Item,
    p.Project AS Project,
    s.car_number,
    p.PO_Year AS PO_Year,
    p.AcctType AS Account_Type,
    p.budget_sublines,
    s.car_type,
    s.requester,
    s.fbn
FROM
    Redshift_PO_Report p
INNER JOIN Redshift_MCL s ON p.Project = s.car_number
WHERE
    s.car_type LIKE 'Datacenter or Room Build - Leased%'
AND p.AcctType = 'CapEx%'
AND s.controls > '0'
AND p.Item_Description LIKE '%BMS%'
OR p.Item_Description LIKE '%EPMS%'
AND p.budget_sublines IN ('BMS', 'EPMS');
```

The problem is that it is returning rows with something other than 'Datacenter...' in the car_type, something other than CapEx in AcctType (OpEx in this case).  The rest seems to work fine.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: parentheses issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is using AND and OR.

Try this:

```
...
AND (p.Item_Description LIKE '%BMS%' OR  p.Item_Description LIKE '%EPMS%')
AND ...
```

In your given code, it either requires all conditions before the "or" to be True, or all conditions after the "or" to be true. Therefore the first conditions may be False, as you are experiencing, as long as everything after "or" is True.

Comment: This returns no results now.

Comment: @us I don't know your data. Is it possible that no data entry fulfills all requirements? Or are you positive, that there should be results?

Comment: I fixed it, it wasn't your change it was another of mine I forgot I made.  This is working now.

Comment: @user2867882 Try s.controls > 0 (without quotation marks). If that works, I will add it to my answer

Comment: @user2867882 I just saw your comment now after commenting. Please enlighten us about what the error was, so it can be added to the solution for others stumbling over this with the same problems.

Comment: I had changed  s.car_type LIKE 'Datacenter or Room Build - Leased%' and then changed it back, but made a typo when I changed it back in Datacnter (just like that)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
AND p.Item_Description LIKE '%BMS%'
        OR  p.Item_Description LIKE '%EPMS%'
```

for

```
AND (p.Item_Description LIKE '%BMS%'
        OR  p.Item_Description LIKE '%EPMS%')
```